# MySQL Insert failing dynamically but working directly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb

I've got a MySQL table with fields `a1`,`a2`,`a3`,`b1`,`...`,`d1`,`d2`, each field was declared as a `BOOLEAN` in the CREATE statement. (I also tried `TINYINT(1)` but had the same problem).

Then I have this PHP function which receives data from an HTML form:

```
public function add($a) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO property_classification 
           (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,c1,c2,c3,d1,d2) 
           VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    // creating the classification_id
    // e.g. "a1a2a3" => ["a1","a2","a3"]
    $classifications = str_split($a['classifications'], 2);
    $data = array();
    // compile $data array
    foreach (self::$classification_fields as $classification) {
        // if user array contained any classification, set to true
        if (in_array($classification, $classifications)) {
            $data[$classification] = "1"; // I tried `true` too
        } else {
            $data[$classification] = "0"; // I tried `false` here
        }
    }
    // set type for binding PDO params
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) settype($data[$key], 'int'); // tried 'bool'
    $this->db->query($sql, $data);
    $a['classification_id'] = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    $this->log($a['classification_id']); // Output: "0"
    ...
```

The output should be a valid ID from 1+, but the insert failed so the `lastInsertId()` returned 0.

I checked what `$sql` compiled to, it came to this:

> INSERT INTO property_classification (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,c1,c2,c3,d1,d2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);

I also output `$data` with the code: `implode(",",$data);` and it gave me this output:

> 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Which was perfect because the input was `"a1a2"`.

The only problem now is I don't understand why the query is failing all the time, because I put the two bits together like so:

> > INSERT INTO property_classification (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,c1,c2,c3,d1,d2) VALUES(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

Then I executed that query in MySQL Query Browser and it worked.

So why is it failing through `PDO`?

---

## DBO class

```
function query($sql, $data) {
    try {
        $this->query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        if (!is_null($data) && is_array($data))
            $this->query->execute($data);
        else
            $this->query->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        array_push($this->log, $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `$this->db->query()` method?

Comment: What does "failing all the time" mean?  Is there an error returned?

Comment: @GordonLinoff by failing I mean it's not inserting so when I check the database directly it didn't insert. I am logging errors but I got a blank error message from my DBO class.

Comment: @calcinai updated the post with it.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the two foreach loops?  There's a bit of redundant behaviour there - you don't need to iterate the `$data` array again to cast the variables, when you could set them as ints to begin with.  You can start by replacing both loops with: `foreach (self::$classification_fields as $classification)
  $data[$classification] = in_array($classification, $classifications) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: PDO's error messages are logged in [errorinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)- can you print that out for us?

Comment: @StevenLiao Thanks for that. I can now confirm there is no error message. The output was: `array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're actually passing an associative array to the PDO, you can bind to named parameters.  The use of `?` or positional placeholders require a standard indexed array.  If you're against using named params, just replace `$data[$classification] =` with `$data[] =`

Try the below.

```
public function add($a) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO property_classification 
           (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,c1,c2,c3,d1,d2) 
           VALUES(:a1,:a2,:a3,:b1,:b2,:b3,:b4,:b5,:b6,:b7,:b8,:c1,:c2,:c3,:d1,:d2);";

    // creating the classification_id
    // e.g. "a1a2a3" => ["a1","a2","a3"]
    $classifications = str_split($a['classifications'], 2);
    $data = array();
    // compile $data array
    foreach (self::$classification_fields as $classification) 
        $data[$classification] = in_array($classification, $classifications) ? 1 : 0;

    $this->db->query($sql, $data);
    $a['classification_id'] = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    $this->log($a['classification_id']); // Output: "0"
```

Comment: I hate it when I do stuff like that! Never realised the whole time I was passing an associative array where as usually I pass a normal array with `?` params. So when I changed to named params i.e. `:a1, :a2` like you suggested it was 100% working. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes!

Comment: Totally agree with you!